# not getting desired output in javascript

Tags: javascript

i was trying to make a javascript program to convert a number between 20 and 100 to in words. so i wrote this-

```
var num = prompt("enter a number");
if (num>20 && num<100)
{
 words(num);
}
else alert("Please enter a number between 20 and 100");

function words(num)
{
var ones = ["","one","two","three","four","five","six", "seven","eight",  "nine"];
var tens = ["", "", "twenty","thirty","fourty","fifty","sixty","seventy","eighty","ninety"];

var div= num/10;
var rem= num%10;

if (rem==0)
    document.write(num+" = "+tens[div]);
else
    document.write(num+" = "+tens[div]+" "+ones[rem]);

}
```

the problem is if i enter 30 ,40 like that numbers which are divisible by 10 i get correct output but if i enter 32 it will show "32 = undefined two".
what did i do wrong?
i am new to JS so dont know much.

Answer (score 2):

`32/10` is `3.2`, not `3`. You must round the result.

Change

```
 var div= num/10;
```

to

```
 var div= Math.floor(num/10);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be doing

```
var rem= num%10;
var div= (num - rem)/10;
```

Because `25/10 = 2.5 not 2`

**Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/voidSO/316owo0h/)**

Comment: i dont have enough reputation to down vote, dont know who did that .

Comment: This looks like a valid alternative. I'd like the downvoter to explain his vote.

Comment: I guess `Math.floor()` is relatively more complex operation then this direct Subtraction. Why to use it unnecessarily?

Comment: yeah,this looks valid and simple without using math().